Would lying down be safer than standing in a free-falling elevator?
It said that the best way to survive a falling elevator is to lie down flat on the floor to distribute the impact evenly on your whole body.
2012 New York Times article:

Q. If I find myself in a free-falling elevator, is there any position that might increase my chance of survival? (Climbing on top of other people is not an acceptable answer.)
A. The best option would be to lie on your back on the floor as flat as possible, said Eliot H. Frank, a research engineer at the Center for Biomedical Engineering at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.
[...]
You might think that bracing yourself or bending your legs would help, but at high G-forces, your legs would simply not be able to support the weight of your body

A 2020 NPR article quotes a book that makes the same claim:

Here's an answer: It popped up in a footnote on the bottom of page 133 in Mary Roach's latest (and very charming) book, Packing for Mars.

[T]he best way to survive in a falling elevator is to lie down on your back. Sitting is bad but better than standing, because buttocks are nature's safety foam. Muscle and fat are compressible: they help absorb the G forces of the impact.


This How to Survive a Falling Elevator, According to Science video makes a similar claim.
There is a good point in the comments, that while in free-fall it would be difficult to lie down, so let's assume you lie down before the elevator starts falling.
Is this the best way to survive? Is it better to distribute the impact on your whole body, rather than for example standing up and trying to reduce the impact for your head?
To make the question clear, would you really have a higher change of surviving on impact when lying down versus standing up and bracing your legs?

How do you lay down flat when an elevator is in free fall? The story is nonsense.

They're playing fast and loose with the expression "free-falling". Ignoring the usual meaning and taking the spirit of the meaning from the context, it would seem to mean "without brakes or restraint by the drive mechanism". Does that seem about right?

@WeatherVane So you're saying that it's impossible for astronauts to get back into their seats or lie down on the floor of their capsule?

@user71659 no, I am saying that unprepared people in an elevator which suddenly goes into free fall will fly around with their limbs flailing. Look what happened on SQ321.

@WeatherVane Not comparable. If people hit the plane ceiling (negative g) then there's necessarily aerodynamic forces involved beyond free fall. In a free fall, you don't fly around, at most (zero g) you stay in the same place until you push. In a skyscraper fall scenario, you'd have many seconds to assume the position.

@user71659 not even astronauts can "lay on the floor" in zero gravity, although they might strap themself into a seat. In zero gravity, you can't 'lay' on anything, and in which direction is 'floor' in a spacecraft? I said "prepared". Nobody in a falling elevator is prepared, trained, or will know how to lay on the floor, even if they have a plan. When a car turned across the path of my motorcycle I had a plan of what to do in that scenario. I had "many seconds" but in the event it was impossible to react in time to put my plan into action. It's your spacecraft that is 'incomparable'.
